# Yii hasAttribute and Custom Fields

Tags: php, yii

How can I use `hasAttribute` with Custom Fields?

Code:

```
if ($model->hasAttribute($attribute)) {
    ...
} else {
    $this->_sendResponse(400, 'Parameter \''.$attribute.'\' is not supported.');
}
```

---

EXAMPLE

Model.php

```
class Model extends CActiveRecord
{

public $customField;
...
```

Code:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->hasAttribute('customField'); // Returns False.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
if (property_exists('Model', $attribute)) {
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

[`hasAttribute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#hasAttribute-detail) will only check for db attributes.